# Using callbacks appropriate as continuations in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, continuations

I'm familiar with callbacks and i know what synchronicity is, but there is still something I'm missing when it comes to continuation passing style. I've got this simple code example where I can't tell how to transform it to asynchronous code based on callbacks in continuation passing style:

```js
function performOrder() {
  var available, placedOrder;
  available = checkCountOnServer(order.item, order.count);
  if (!available) {
    showNotAvailableMessage(order);
    return;
  }
  placedOrder = checkPayment(order.item, order.count, order.paymentMethod);
  if (askUserForConfirmationWithDialog(placedOrder)) {
    return confirmOrder(placedOrder);
  }
}
```

My approach to this was:

```js
function performOrder() {
  checkCountOnServerC(order.item, order.count, showNotAvailableMessage(order));
  return checkPaymentC(order.item, order.count, askUserConfirmationWithDialogC(placedOrder, confirmOrder(placedOrder));
}
```

All Methods appended with C can be assumed to be modified to accept a callback as continuation.

My Questions are: Are both snippets equivalent and confirms the second one to the continuation passing style?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would execute `checkCountOnServerC` and `checkPaymentC` in parallel regardless of the status of `available`. Therefore they are not equivalent.

The correct transformation would depend on the style you want to adopt: node.js standard callback style, Promises, successCallback/errorCallback etc. Assuming you want to use node.js standard callback style:

```
function performOrderC(callback){
    checkCountOnServerC(order.item, order.count, function(err, available){
        if (! available ) {
            showNotAvailableMessage(order));
            callback(new Error('Not available'));
            return;
        } 
        checkPaymentC(order.item, order.count, function(err, placedOrder){
            askUserConfirmationWithDialogC(placedOrder, function(){
                callback(null, confirmOrder(placedOrder)); // this is how you "return" results
           });
       });
    });
}
```

Node.js standard callback style uses the first argument of callbacks to pass errors up the stack. But before node.js this was not universally adopted by asynchronous functions.

If the above appears a bit dense (sometimes called callback-hell) you can always refactor it to not use anonymous functions:

```
function checkPaymentHandler (callback) {
    return function (err, placedOrder){
        askUserConfirmationWithDialogC(placedOrder, function(){
            callback(null, confirmOrder(placedOrder)); // this is how you "return" results
        });
    });
}

function checkCountHandler (callback) {
    return function (err, available) {
        if (! available ) {
            showNotAvailableMessage(order));
            callback(new Error('Not available'));
            return;
        } 
        checkPaymentC(order.item, order.count, checkPaymentHandler(callback));
    }
}

function performOrderC(callback){
    checkCountOnServerC(order.item, order.count, checkCountHandler(callback));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much slebetman! It's already much clearer for me. 

There is not a special style i want to adopt. I just want to understand this "continuation passing style" with as basic javascript as possible.

What is the difference between returning callback() and just calling it and is the result of confirmOrder(placedOrder) in the first code snippet the return value of performOrderC()?

Comment: This may be a little bit offtopic but it's somehow related. When chaining promises like: **doSomething().then(...).then( function() { .... return value});** how to gain access to the last return value in this case value. Im kind of getting the feeling that these kinds of constructs are not intended to work much with values beeing passed upwards and more to make use of side effects of the methods called.

Comment: With regards to returning callback, it's just to break program flow with return and not execute the following code. I'll edit the example to be clearer.

Comment: The key to asynchronous code in any language is that you don't pass values up but pass code down. Note that the code you want to execute is `callback` so you pass it down to where/when the value becomes available. Promises is just a design pattern where instead of passing the callback down it returns an object (a promise) with a `.then()` method that allows you to pass a callback down. With ES6 promises gains a syntax sugar with `async/await` that emulates passing value up but under the hood the compiler just re-arranges the code to pass the rest of the function down the promise

Comment: Note that although people call this continuation passing style it has nothing to do with either continuation or real continuation passing style. This is simply passing functions - it is more related to monads than continuations. The funny thing is javascript actually has continuations in the form of generators (functions marked with `*`) and the `yield` keyword which was introduced a full two years before promises but never became popular (except in the Koa framework which uses a continuation based design pattern called trampolines)

Comment: So you are saying that the return statement in both cases (Promises and Callback) on the lowest level (e.g. last then()) can't return values and is only used for breaking the programflow? 

What would i do if i intended to have performOrderC() return the result of confirmOrder(placedOrder) instead of using it in the passed callback of performOrderC()?

Thank you so much for helping me out. Im new to Javascript and coming from Java. Understanding JS is somehow really hard for me. Im not used to having so many things happen implicitly.

Comment: Promises are a bit different. When you return from within a `.then()` or `.catch()` method of a promise there is some outer logic that takes the value returned and wrap it in a promise before returning that promise. This allows you to "return" values from inside a promise by simply using **return**. The promise will later call the callback you pass to `.then()` and pass the value as the argument